# How to change sparkline background color within Kendo UI

Tags: user-interface, colors, kendo-ui, background, sparklines

```
$("#spark-collector").kendoSparkline({
    type: "line",
    data: [
        71, 70, 69, 68, 65, 60, 55, 55, 50, 52,
        73, 72, 72, 71, 68, 63, 57, 58, 53, 55,
        63, 59, 61, 64, 58, 53, 48, 48, 45, 45,
        63, 64, 63, 67, 58, 56, 53, 59, 51, 54
    ],
    valueAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    },
    seriesColors: ["blue"],
    tooltip: {
        visible: true
    }
});
```

How to change sparkline background color within Kendo UI?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use PlotArea for that. Please refer to the documentation. You can set Background, border, margin, opacity and padding

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/PlotArea/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the property `chartArea.background`. Referring to your example:

```
$("#spark-collector").kendoSparkline({
    type: "line",
    charArea: {
        background: "cyan"
    },
    data: [
        71, 70, 69, 68, 65, 60, 55, 55, 50, 52,
        73, 72, 72, 71, 68, 63, 57, 58, 53, 55,
        63, 59, 61, 64, 58, 53, 48, 48, 45, 45,
        63, 64, 63, 67, 58, 56, 53, 59, 51, 54
    ],
    valueAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    },
    seriesColors: ["blue"],
    tooltip: {
        visible: true
    }
});
```

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/sparkline/configuration/chartarea#chartArea.background)

Following a code snippet...

```js
$("#spark-collector").kendoSparkline({
  type: "line",
  chartArea: {
    background: "cyan"
  },
  data: [
    71, 70, 69, 68, 65, 60, 55, 55, 50, 52,
    73, 72, 72, 71, 68, 63, 57, 58, 53, 55,
    63, 59, 61, 64, 58, 53, 48, 48, 45, 45,
    63, 64, 63, 67, 58, 56, 53, 59, 51, 54
  ],
  valueAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  },
  seriesColors: ["blue"],
  tooltip: {
    visible: true
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.bootstrap-v4.min.css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="spark-collector"></div>
```